# To make amends from the other side

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Suppose somebody has wronged me, and I want them to make amends. Say I ask for an apology. What are my efforts called? Am I also making amends, or is there a word/phrase that describes the action of trying to get somebody else to make amends?

Comment: you are in effect trying to make amends.

Comment: I think you are ***demanding an apology.***

Comment: You're seeking *compensation, restitution,* etc. To my mind, giving an *apology* wouldn't normally count as *making amends", so [apologise and make amends](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22apologise+and+make+amends%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) isn't just meaningless repetition.

Comment: For such demand, you may use **request for [an] apology**

Comment: 'Seeking satisfaction' is perhaps used more generally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the definitions of ***appeal*** is:

> : to try to make someone do or accept something as right or proper by saying things that are directed at a person's feelings, attitudes, etc.
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/appeal)</sub>

Comment: A typical expression is: *appeal to their sense of right and wrong*.

Answer (score 0):

As the wronged party, you want the *offender* to make amends; that is not *you* making amends.

One tactic commonly used when one person is seeking (eg. an apology) from another, is to employ the classic "***guilt trip***".

So to describe taking this action, you might say: "I **guilt-tripped** him/her into doing what I wanted."

Comment: I know this is a much broader term than what your specific situation asks for, but it's as close to it as I can think of at the moment.

Comment: Please don't guilt-trip me!  I'll respond much better if you give me a straightforward **I-message**.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I-message.